# How to pass a link to Facebook iPhone app status update?

Tags: iphone, html, facebook

It's possible to create href-attibutes that makes the iPhone quit Safari and launch another app. For the official Twitter-app this would look like:

```
<a href="twitter:///post?message=my+important+message">Click to deliver message to Twitter-apps status updater</a>
```

For the Facebook-app the protocoll is:

```
fb:///
```

But i can't figure out, or find any information about, how to get my message (a url to share) directly into the the status updater.

Is there a url-scheme, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

http://iphonedevtools.com/?p=302 lists a bunch of URIs that can be used, but none appear to allow sharing a link (or any query string whatsoever).